# execute two shell commands in single exec php statement

Tags: php, exec

I want to display all the files that are modified after a specified date

the commands are

```
touch --date '2011-09-19 /home/  , find /home/
```

How i can execute this two commands in single exec statement.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use either a `;` or a `&&` to separate the comands. The `;` runs both commands unconditionally. If the first one fails, the second one still runs. Using `&&` makes the second command depend on the first. If the first command fails, the second will NOT run.

```
command1 ; command2     (run both uncondtionally)
command1 && command2     (run command2 only if command1 succeeds)
```

Comment: Amazing!! spent so much efforts using Process but this one works like wonders :) Thank you

Answer (score 5):

This is how I did it simultaneously encode thumbs, and then flv video..I need to generate 2 thumbs from avi file. After the thumbs I need to convert the same avi to flv or whatever. So, here is the code I normally used.

```
$command_one = "do whatever the script does best";
$command_two = "do whatever the script does second best";
//execute and redirect standard stream ..
@exec($command_one."&& ".$command_two.">/dev/null 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null &");
```

You can also run array of commands with exec, if you want :)

```
foreach($crapatoids as $crap){

$command_name = $crap;
//exec the crap below
@exec ($command_name." >/dev/null 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null &");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seperate them with a semicolon (;). Example:

```
exec("touch --date '2011-09-19' /home/; find /home/");
```

Comment: Try the line of code I posted. It should work - provided the commands' syntax is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The semicolon separator allows you to run multiple commands on one line.

```
<?php
    $output = shell_exec("touch --date '2011-09-19' /home/; find /home/");
    echo "<pre>" . $output . "</pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, my problem came from execution python file in a virtual environment of Python. Generally, Python website instructs us to go through command lines: create a virtual env --> activate it --> call Python file (e.g: `python3 yourPyFile.py`). However, when I was trying to adapt these steps through calling in php with `exec()` method, it didn't work. Finally, I found out you don't need to activate env at all, what you only need to use a python which already generated when you creating virtual env by `path/to/virtual/env/bin/python3 yourPyFile.py`.