# How to exec shell commands through php

Tags: php, shell

I am trying to execute shell commands using php.
How to execute those **commands** listed in comments.

Comment: cd "filelocation" and node filename

Comment: You tried the standard PHP functions that execute shell commands? What was the outcome?

Comment: Am i right thinking you want to run execute 'php' within your php code? e.g. `php somephp.php`

Comment: no i am usig node js .to run a file in node we need to move the cmd prompt to that folder location and need to type the command 'node filename'.if i use the native php command it is saying fatal error

Comment: So first you need to `cd` to that folder and then execute the command? Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7122994/4768218

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your webservers configuration. I'm using phpseclib to execute shell commands through php but depending on what you need, a simple shell_exec() could be enough.

Answer (score 0):

`shell_exec("script.sh");`

[For more Informations](http://php.net/manual/de/function.shell-exec.php)

Comment: in shell_exec is able to open file.but not able to execute line node sample js.how to do shell-exec(' node sample');shell exec('cd filepath');