# How to execute two CMD queries in PHP simultaneously

Tags: php, exec

```
$command1 = "interfacename -S ipaddress -N nms -P company ";
$command2 = "list search clientclass hardwareaddress Mac address ";
if ( exec( $command1 . "&&" . $command2 ) ) {
    echo "successfuly executed";
} else {
    echo "Not successfuly executed";
}
```

If command 1 (cmd query) successfully executed, I want command 2 (which also contains some cmd queries) to be executed next. In the above script, only command 1 is executed. It doesn’t show any result for command 2.

I have wasted two days on this without finding any solution.

Comment: That doesn't resolve my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shell_exec()` PHP function to run `Shell Command` directly in your script.

> **Syntax :** string shell_exec (string $cmd)

**Example :**

```
$output = shell_exec('ls -lart');
var_dump($output);  #Showing the outputs
```

> You can use multiple conditions in a single command line.

**Example :**

```
$data   = "rm a.txt && echo \"Deleted\"";
$output = exec($data);
var_dump($output);

if($output=="Deleted"){
   #Successful
}
```

In above example `"Deleted"` string will assign to `$output` when the file deleted successfully. Otherwise the `error/warning/empty` string will assign to `$output` variable. You should make condition with `$output` string.

Here is the documentation of [shell_exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)

**Note :** There will be a `new line` character of the function `shell_exec()` output.

Comment: how to do simultaneous conditional cmd queries execution by using shell_exec?

Comment: i am waiting for your answer @Sumon Sarker

Answer (score 0):

You can use either a `;` or a `&&` to separate the comands. The `;` runs both commands unconditionally. If the first one fails, the second one still runs. Using `&&` makes the second command depend on the first. If the first command fails, the second will NOT run. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122742/execute-two-shell-commands-in-single-exec-php-statement?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: I have used && operator but it doesn't work @Krishanaraj

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to execute `$command1` and then execute `$command2` only if `$command1` succeeds.

The way you tried, by joining the commands with `&&` is the correct way in a shell script (and it works even with the PHP function [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)). But, because your script is written in PHP, let's do it in the PHP way (in fact, it's the same way but we let PHP do the logical `AND` operation).

Use the PHP function [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) to run each command and pass three arguments to it. The second argument (`$output`, passed by reference) is an array variable. `exec()` appends to it the output of the command. The third argument (`$return_var`, also passed by reference) is a variable that is set by `exec()` with the exit code of the executed command.

The convention on Linux/Unix programs is to return `0` exit code for success and a (one byte) positive value (`1`..`255`) for errors. Also, the `&&` operator on the Linux shell knows that `0` is success and a non-zero value is an error.

Now, the PHP code:

```
$command1 = "ipcli -S 192.168.4.2 -N nms -P nmsworldcall ";
$command2 = "list search clientclassentry hardwareaddress 00:0E:09:00:00:01";

// Run the first command
$out1  = array();
$code1 = 0;
exec($command1, $out1, $code1);

// Run the second command only if the first command succeeded
$out2  = array();
$code2 = 0;
if ($code1 == 0) {
    exec($command2, $out2, $code2);
}

// Output the outcome
if ($code1 == 0) {
    if ($code2 == 0) {
       echo("Both commands succeeded.\n");
    } else {
       echo("The first command succeeded, the second command failed.\n");
    }
} else {
    echo("The first command failed, the second command was skipped.\n");
}
```

After the code ends, `$code1` and `$code2` contain the exit codes of the two commands; if `$code1` is not zero then the first command failed and `$code2` is zero but the second command was not executed.

`$out1` and `$out2` are arrays that contain the output of the two commands, split on lines.

Comment: In above code command 2 isn't executed.It directly goes to else part and echo(The first command succeeded, the second command failed.\n)

Comment: It reports what happened. The second command returned an exit code different than `0` or it didn't run at all. What is the value of `$code2`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to know about simultaneous execution but I'm sure about one cmd dependent on another cmd execution action. Here I'm running single execution cmd first to clear all set path, second I've declared my file path, third I install angular cmd `npm install`.

```
    $path = "D:/xampp/htdocs/tests/omni-files-upload/aa-test/src";
        $command_one = "cd /";
        $command_two = "cd ".$path;
        $command_three = "npm install";
        
        @exec($command_one."&& ".$command_two."&& ".$command_three);
```